# I want to create a format in Excel to trigger a colour code

Tags: microsoft-excel

Currently I have a drop down list on certain cells, connected to a list of statuses. 'Complete' which marks as green, 'Pending' which marks as orange, 'Outstanding' which marks as Red. I want each drop down option to also trigger a cell colour change. 
For example, if cell H23 is set as 'Complete' from the drop down bar, I want cell H22 to automatically change to 'Complete'. However if cell H23 is set as 'Complete' from their drop down menu, and cell 'H24' is set as outstanding, I then want it to change cell H23 to change colour and status automatically to orange.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, you want H22 to reflect the colour and value of H23 (Which is a drop down). However, if H24 is outstanding, you want H23 to say outstanding and turn orange? But at the top you said that Outstanding is red. You need to clarify. What is your data? Is it in columns? How many columns? How many hows? And what exactly do you want them to do, it's just not clear enough.

Comment: From your question - I feel that the color of the present cell depends on the color of its successive cell in a given column - Is that what you want?

Comment: Have you tried using Conditional Formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not terribly clear, as other posters have stated, but I've added a sample file with a macro that I think meets your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim PreviousRowStatus As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("H:H")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Did a change occur to the status column (other than the column header?
        If Range(Target.Address).Column = "8" And Range(Target.Address).Row <> 1 _
        And Range(Target.Address).Row <> 2 Then ' Column H is column 8

            ' If the values are already the same, there's no need to make an update.
            If Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> Target.Value Then

                ' Update the value of the previous row to match newly entered row
                Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Target.Value

                ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has changed.
                ' MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address & " has changed to " & _
                Target.Value & " to match data in subsequent row."

            End If

        End If

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The colors are set automatically using conditional formatting. If you want to know more about how this works, please see the links below.

- [Overview with video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx)
- [Details](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-change-find-or-clear-conditional-formats-HP010342157.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010370614%23BM10)

Comment: I can't figure out how to attach files to Superuser, but I threw together an Excel proof of concept at http://dropcanvas.com/qkimj.

Comment: I don't know how to attach files, but I put a working sample at http://dropcanvas.com/qkimj, which should remain active for three days. Please check and let me know if this works for you. Other more advanced Superuser folks, can you tell me how I can attach files? I tried searching the help, and couldn't find anything.